# Get a list of @Parameters in a T-SQL script with its datatype

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

From a T-SQL script like this:

```
Select 
    Proveedor.RazonSocial, Articulo.ArticuloId As Código, 
    Articulo.Descripcion As Descripción
From
    Articulo
Inner Join 
    Suministrador On (Articulo.OID = Suministrador.Articulo)
Inner Join 
    Proveedor On (Suministrador.Proveedor = Proveedor.OID)
Where 
    Proveedor.ProveedorId = @CodigoDeProveedor
```

I would like to get a list containing `@CodigoDeProveedor` and its datatype inferred from the database table (in this case it's int)

Are there any stored procedures or script I can use to do this?

Clarification:

- The SQL is a script, not a Stored Procedure.
- I want to parse the parameters and find out their data type so I can mount a GUI screen where I can ask the end user the values they want to apply to the script.
- Currently, I am passing the TSQL text and resolving the parameters this way. I just didn't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Please Provide more information.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115881/how-to-get-stored-procedure-parameters-details

Comment: I think there are no easy ways, unless you want to parse tsql. What problem are you actually trying to solve? Plus, just because a column has datatype X, it doesn't mean the parameter has it

Comment: Where is this list of parameters coming from - ad hoc SQL? A procedure? What are you using this information *for*? You have not shown exactly what your desired results are either.

Comment: This is not duplicated with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115881/how-to-get-stored-procedure-parameters-details as I'm not using stored procedures.

Comment: That's a query, not a script, and the parameter has no type. If you had a stored procedure or actual script, the type would be the one in the parameter or variable definition. If you execute this from a client, the type is whatever the client specifies.

Comment: This really sounds like an XY-problem - a parameter type and its usage in a query cannot change, you should know in advance if you are expecting an int, a date etc. If you really want to make this dynamic in some way have your own list of params and type mappings you can look up from a config or enum list etc- but I don't think your "wheel" is a very common scenario.

Comment: @MartinHT, parameters, including data types and values, are specified in app code and passed along with the SQL query text. Are you asking how to determine the proper parameter type matching the referenced `Proveedor.ProveedorId` column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`sp_describe_undeclared_parameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-undeclared-parameters-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) system procedure.

```sql
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = N'
Select 
    Proveedor.RazonSocial, Articulo.ArticuloId As Código, 
    Articulo.Descripcion As Descripción
From
    Articulo
Inner Join 
    Suministrador On (Articulo.OID = Suministrador.Articulo)
Inner Join 
    Proveedor On (Suministrador.Proveedor = Proveedor.OID)
Where 
    Proveedor.ProveedorId = @CodigoDeProveedor
';

EXEC sp_describe_undeclared_parameters @query;
```

But it can fail in many situations, not least when a parameter is used twice.